# Why is the Frame property null in a pivot item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a pivot page defined like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
    <Pivot Title="JOETZ">
        <PivotItem Header="kampen" Name="PvOne">
            <views:CampsPage/>
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem Header="kalender" Name="PvTwo">
            <views:CalendarPage/>
        </PivotItem>

        <PivotItem Header="profiel" Name="PvThree">
            <views:LoginPage/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Taking the first page (`CampsPage`) as an example: it contains a `ListBox` with an overview of camps. when an item is clicked, it should go to a detailview. In order to navigate I figured this should've been enough:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(CampDetail), selectedCamp);
```

but this throws a `NullReferenceException` because `Frame` is apparently `null`.

On the other hand, doing navigation like this works:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
if (frame == null) { return; }
frame.Navigate(typeof(CampDetail), selectedCamp);
```

And so does this approach:

```
var frame = ((App) Application.Current).RootFrame;
frame.Navigate(typeof(CampDetail), selectedCamp);
```

Why isn't the `Frame` property set in a pivot item? And as a followup: how should I navigate from pivot items?

Comment: Your `CampsPage` is not inside the *Frame* - you haven't navigated to it. You have set it inside *Pivot* container, thus it's *Frame* property is `null`. Inside `Window.Current.Content` is *Page* with `LayoutRoot`, maybe you can pass a handler to your pivot items.

Comment: @Romasz: I see what you're getting at but it's unclear to me how you would solve this. What do you mean by "passing a handler to the pivot items"?

Comment: I forgot to add that it should be possible to put your pivotitem pages inside frames. Then each of those frames will have its own navigation history. This should work, but also will complicate other things.

Comment: What is the problem with the two approaches for navigation that you mentioned?

Comment: @yasen: not necessarily a problem per sé, it's just not as fluent as `Frame.Navigate` with the casting involved. It made me wonder whether it can be done with simpler syntax (perhaps there is a shortcut through some property?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've already found most of the info that you need. I can confirm that is the way to navigate (as you suggested yourself):

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
frame.Navigate(typeof(CampDetail), selectedCamp);
```

Getting the `Frame` this way is pretty common and safe. There won't be anything other than a `Frame` in the `Window.Current.Content` unless *you* have put it there. In which case, there simply won't be a `Frame`, and you won't be able to navigate like this anyway (that is, you'll have to manually change the `Window.Current.Content` property to show other content, and manually manage the back button).

**Some ideas/suggestions**

I'd suggest you create a static class with a static `Navigate` method, which does the work (gets the Frame and invokes its `Navigate` method).

Perhaps even more convinient would be to (also) make an extension method to the UserControl class that does the navigation. This way you would simply be calling `this.Navigate(typeof(CampDetail), selectedCamp)` in all UserControls.

I'd also suggest to be consistent and always use this method and never use the `Page.Frame` property (unless you really need to, for some reason).
This would make finding/resolving problems related to navigation easier, as every navigation would be going through that method.

**You should use UserControl instead of Page**

A `Page` is a part of the app that is to be displayed on the whole screen. It is not indended to be a part of another page. The way you use it, it works like a UserControl (which is what you should be using in this case). The `Page`-specific features would only work if you navigate to it, using the `Frame` object.

User controls and templated controls on the other hand, are reusable parts of pages. So, if you need to have some UI (with its functionality) in more than one page - you make one of these controls.

So, I'd suggest you change `<views:CampsPage/>`, `<views:CalendarPage/>` and `<views:LoginPage/>` to be UserControls instead of Pages. If you need pages as well (for navigation purposes), make pages that just display these UserControls.

**Hardware Back button**

You don't seem to need this anymore, but I'll put a few lines anyway.

By default the Back button just <s>tells the `Frame` in the `Window.Current.Content` to `GoBack()` if possible</s> closes the app. You can manually handle the back button and do some non-default action by using the `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event.

**Edit**

I was wrong about the back button's default action and fixed it. I'm pretty sure it used to automatically navigate back through the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the best answer (I'm sure it's not :) but should work.

The problem is that `CampsPage` is as I suspect a *Page* class inside other container than a *Frame*. You haven't navigeted to that page, it's not inside `Window.Current.Content` - it's inside *Pivot*. Thus it's *Frame* property is `null`.

Here is my *ugly* approach:

Extend your *Page* class with a *DependencyProperty* - a reference to parent page:

```cs
public class ExtendedPage : Page
{
    public Page ParentPage
    {
        get { return (Page)GetValue(ParentPageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParentPageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentPageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ParentPage", typeof(Page), typeof(Page), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Then make your `CampsPage` (and other) this *ExtendedPage* type. Then bind *ParentPage* property to current *Page* inside the frame:

```
<Page Name="MyMainPage" ... rest of things ...>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Pivot Title="JOETZ">
            <PivotItem Header="kampen" Name="PvOne">
                <local:CampsPage ParentPage="{Binding ElementName=MyMainPage}"/>
            </PivotItem>

... rest of the code
```

Then you can navigate in your `CampsPage` like this:

```cs
ParentPage.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage));
```

Like I've said there are probably beter solutions, but unless there is no other, maybe this will be useful.

An example you [can download from GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/UsingPageInsidePivotItem).

Comment: It seems rather hacky indeed but if there's no better option I'll consider it (although the ways I have it working now might just be easier then). Will this create a correct navigationstack? i.e. if I go to pivotpage 1, pivotpage 2 and then press the hardware backbutton, will it go back to pivotpage 1?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel What do you mean by pivotpage1 and pivotpage2? Let's say that you have your `MyMainPage` with pivot and its items, you click on `CampsPage` it goes to detail page. When you hit back button it will return to `MyMainPage`, the same with detail page of second pivotitem.

Comment: With 'pivotpage1' and 'pivotpage2' I'm referring to two pivotitems. Say that I go to `CampsPage' and then go to the second pivotitem and press back; will it return me to the `CampsPage` pivotitem or will it return me to the previous page (which in my actual app is some sort of launch menu)?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If you go to your second pivotitem by swiping, then you are not navigating, but just changing pivotitems. In this situation when you hit back button then you will be navigated to your previous page that was inside the frame - launch menu (or the app will exit).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Your 'Page' inside pivotitem is not a Page to which you navigate - it's just a container for other items.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the clarification. I'll leave this question open a bit longer and perhaps throw a bounty at it to see if there is a more established approach, otherwise I'll go with this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes, maybe someone knows better/easier solution - I would also like to know a better approach.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel How would you like the hardware back button to work in the situation you described?

Comment: @yasen: after thinking it through a bit more, the backbutton should work in a way that it views all pivotitems as one entry in the navigationstack (i.e.: the way it is now).